# Need explicit import UIKit to all UIKit subclasses in project after import my framework

Tags: ios, swift, ios-frameworks

Need explicit import UIKit to all UIKit subclasses in a project after import my framework.

I decided to export all **objective-c classes** from my project and make a Framework. 
I created the Framework with a **Google map Framework**. For thar you must add  UIKit Framework to your project too. 
I built a universal MyFramework then added to my project. 
And after that, I tried to compile the project but there were compile errors. Every class, for example with subclassing UIView needed to import UIKit.

There are a thousand classes where I must add "import UIKit". 
How can I fix that?

UPD:
I tried to add "#import MyFramewrok.h" into a bridging file of my project and this worked fine, because it has importing of UIKit. But I think it's not a proper solution.

Answer (score -1):

1. Tap on your project
2. Choose General tab (you should already be there)
3. Scroll to Linked Frameworks and Libraries and tap on the + button
4. Choose UIKit
5. Recompile and you're done

End result:

[image]

Comment: No, I have tried yet this solution. But I have added a header of MyFramework into bridging file and it solved the problem. But it's the strange solution I think.